# Dynamically change specific tab colors using a row of cells from one sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a workbook with about 65 tabs/sheets. I have one specific worksheet with a status column with dropdowns for "Not started", "Incomplete" and "Completed". Based on the entry in a range of cell from D3:D65 on one sheet named "CONTENTS", I need the tab colors to update with the selection. I know how to accomplish this doing it one by one with the code below, but I'm looking for a loop which can use the status from D3:D65 on the CONTENTS sheet to update each corresponding sheet. Please help!

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Select Case Sheets("CONTENTS").Range("D3").Value
         Case "Not Started"
             Sheets("Introduction 800-171").Tab.color = vbRed
         Case "Incomplete"
             Sheets("Introduction 800-171").Tab.color = vbYellow
         Case "Completed"
             Sheets("Introduction 800-171").Tab.color = RGB(0, 120, 60)
         End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want your event handler to be responding specifically to changes on CONTENTS, and not on every sheet?  Is the sheet name included on CONTENTS?

Comment: That is correct. The CONTENTS sheet is a table of contents with dropdown beside each sheet name with different actions. Depending on the action corresponding with the sheet, I want it to update the tab with the matching name.

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting this in the worksheet code for CONTENTS. I am assuming the sheet name is in column A.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Dim shName As String

For Each rng In Target
    If Not Intersect(rng, Range("D3:D3")) Is Nothing Then
        shName = rng.Offset(0, -3).Value
        Select Case rng.Value
            Case "Not Started"
                Sheets(shName).Tab.Color = vbRed
            Case "Incomplete"
                Sheets(shName).Tab.Color = vbYellow
            Case "Completed"
                Sheets(shName).Tab.Color = RGB(0, 120, 60)
        End Select
    End If
Next rng
End Sub
```

The  D3:D3 will have to changed to the actual range of statuses and the offset will have to be changed if the sheet name isn't in column A.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I'll give it a whirl and see what happens. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the sheet names?

If they are a corresponding column to the status, let's say column C, you could use something like this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Sheets("CONTENTS").Range("D3:D65").Cells
        Set ws = Sheets(cell.Offset(, -1).Value)
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "Not Started"
                ws.Tab.Color = vbRed
            Case "Incomplete"
                ws.Tab.Color = vbYellow
            Case "Completed"
                ws.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 120, 60)
        End Select
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. 

There are a number of sheets as I mentioned. Is there a way to do this without calling out each specific sheets. Let's say I wanted to start from the 3rd sheet called "DNS" to the 65th sheet called "Mac OS". Is there a way I can assign the colors from the range of cells in CONTENTS D3:D65 above to that specific range. I don't want the first or last few worksheets to be included. Thanks!